# default field permissions

Tags: users

I have created a module that adds a an extra field for each user. I do this by first creating the field using field_create_field and then I bind it to the user object using field_create_instance. This is standard practice I think.

Now, I would like to add so that by default only administrators should be able to change the value of this field. I would like to keep down the number of external modules, so if possible I would like this to be the default behavior after installing my module, without relying on other modules such as field_permissions to achieve this.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything is possible, but read help center. Questions about your code should contain said code, or at least part of code relevant f to the question.

Comment: all you're doing is creating your own external module to handle it, so I fail to see the value... but, since you know field_permissions does what you want - why not just look at the code for that module and incorporate bits and pieces into yours?

Comment: @Geoff: Thanks! All I needed was the hook_field_access hook, and I found it when looking through the source on field_permissions. So from now on I know that whenever there is a problem, the approach is to search for something that does something similar to what I want, then look at the source...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is done using the hook_field_access. In my case, what I did was:

```
function my_module_field_access($op, $field, $type, $entity) {
    if ($op=="edit" && $field["field_name"]=="my_field") {
        if (!user_access("administer users"))
            return FALSE;
    }
}
```